# How do I get of joomla's custom field group and its content

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

How do I query the joomla custom field group and its content (if it exists)? I want the content of field groups to be "implemented" in the joomla's template com_content/article/default.php file. My basic concept already exists, I want to see the contents of each group under different tabs. I could ask about the content of the fields, but unfortunately I can not access the field groups. Can somebody give me some help in this? Thanks in advance!

(In my example I'm not interested of the user groups.)

For example: I have created three field groups with different fields. (in this example only the field group names are listed, Field group 1, Field group 2, Field group 3). I would like to display the content of the field groups: (Field group 1 content, Field group 2 content, Field group 3 content)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Field group 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Field group 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Field group 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Field group 1 content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Field group 2 content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Field group 3 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to construct the query? or how to implement the query that does the job?

Comment: I want to display the result. No matter whether it is a database query or a query of fields.php. Tthe second might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
// GET YOUR CUSTOM FIELDS

$myCustomFields = array();
    foreach($this->item->jcfields as $field) {
        $myCustomFields[$field->name] = $field->value; } 

// Value of Custom Field with the Field Name "Custom_Field_Content"

$Custom_Field_Content = $myCustomFields['Custom_Field_Content'];
```

Now you can use PHP to insert the Value

```
<?php if (!empty($Custom_Field_Content)) echo $Custom_Field_Content; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your job, KlintWeb. But this is not what i need. For your result you need <?php JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php'); ?> too because you must register Joomla's fields.php file too. What i need is a separeted/categorized list of the field values.

Comment: Turn it into an array and order by group?

Comment: You don't need anything else, if you makes an override in  Joomla's template com_content/article/default.php

Comment: KlintWeb you're right. I apologize for my ignorance. First I created an overwrite, but I did not even watch the line at the beginning of the file, which already registers/calls the helpers. It's almost done. If I have it, will share it.